# Cannot attach the file 'DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection' (using MySQL with ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

i am trying to connect to mysql database and i have follow the correct steps for using it into ASP.NET, but when running the web app the following error apears:

Cannot attach the file 'C:...\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection'.

does anyone know why?

i have already tried adding a providerName tag unto providers tag that reference MySql.Data.MySqlClient thinking that possibly the problem is over there but dont think so, and the problem didnt get resolved.

code snippett: **<
add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password='';database=datahub"
        providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />**

Believe the problem is over this line of code beacuse when i added it the problem was presented.

Comment: Does your connectionstring look like this?  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost; user id=root; password=myrootpass; persist security info=True; database=mytestdb" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /

Comment: ooh sorry, no the code doesnt looks like yours, the code snippet isnt shown in the post, i will correct the post but the code is:<add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password='';database=datahub"
        providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />